# how to align image top right to the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to align the asset to the top right side of the screen,
I also tried `positioned` widgets. but that didn't help. and I'm also kinda new at flutter. so is there any other widget to achieve this?

here is the code i tried

```
Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/design_el_1.png',
              alignment: Alignment.topRight
            ),
           
               other elements
               other elements
               other elements
            ]
          );
```

[image]

I want to align the lite purple element on the top, how can I align the image to the top right of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use Align Widget like the code given below

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: Image.asset("Assets/user.png"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/onboard.jpeg',
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
               ],
            )
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the widget with `Align`

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Image.asset("images/demo.png"),
        ),
        Image.asset("images/demo.png"),
        Image.asset("images/demo.png"),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Image.asset` with `Align` widget and use it's `alignment: Alignment.centerRight` property. Your image will surely align right side.

```
 Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: Image.asset("Assets/user.png"))
```

P.S :- You may use your asset image instead of my image :)

[image: Output]